# Can a CustomEvent be dispatched to multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am creating a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) and I then want to dispatch it to an arbitrary number of elements.  It seems like I could make this more efficient if I only create the `CustomEvent` once and pass it to `dispatchEvent` on every element in question, rather than constructing it for each `dispatchEvent` call.  However, I don't see anything regarding whether this is allowed or whether dispatching the event effectively renders the event worthless for future dispatching.

Comment: good question, but this is a case where testing is quicker than asking jerks like us...

Comment: @dandavis right, well... that will only prove that/if it works for the specific instances where it is tested.  in my experience javascript in a web browser is a particularly easy environment to get bitten by things that appear to work but which you shouldn't do.

Comment: its just something i've never heard of doing, or seen done, so i'd be surprised if anyone had a learned take on it. given that, it's basically just something that a fellow reader would try in a few browsers and report back, which you should do for us, since it's a good question and nobody here knows...

Comment: "like I could make this more efficient if I only create the CustomEvent once" - you overestimate the computational cost of a single JavaScript object.